# How OS restricts the way of procedure call?

Tags: windows, operating-system, cpu-architecture, abi, function-call

There are two ways of procedure call, save address to register or save it in stack. I read that the way of procedure call is OS specific. I want to understand how OS restricts that. Can't compiler generate a code that saves address in register and load it later, or save it in stack and pop it when needed?
Just want to understand the role of OS here.

Thank you.

Comment: Actually it is ABI-specific. OSes typically adopt an Application Binary Interface (which also identifies caller/callee save registers and how arguments and return values are passed) to allow calls across compilation units (e.g., using shared libraries). A compiler can choose to ignore the ABI for internal calls (using knowledge of the caller/callee a compiler can even avoid some register saving operations), but it is common for the compiler to simply adopt the ABI for all calls. Since the callee needs to use the return address to return to the caller, the callee needs to know where it is.

Comment: I got what needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operating system has no function in it whatsoever, except that the OS's own libraries may use a specific calling convention.The compiler determines the calling convention. Its' not OS specific but rather language and compiler specific.

Programming languages do things in different ways. For example, the nested procedures of Ada and Pascal need context passed to them behind the scenes that are not needed in C and C++.

In the old days there was pretty much chaos on this.

By the late 1970's the VMS operating system had a calling convention defined and all compilers made by the vendor complied with it. This made it possible for Fortran to call Pascal to call C to call Fortran. However, even there, things were not 100% transparent. In fact, the VMS compilers had extensions to languages to call function in other languages. In FORTRAN 77, everything was passed by reference. There had to extensions to call C function that expected everything to be passed by value.